# How to query against a mdf file I attached in SQL Server in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008-r2

Hell all,

I just attached a mdf file in SQL Server 2008, and everything is working correctly. Now I want to open visual studio, and query against the mdf file I just attached, is there a local version of the connection string that needs to go in to web.config?

If I leave SQL Server open will it act as an instance of the database while I am working on the site in Visual Studio? Or am I suppose to run it somehow?

Any info would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use Data Source=(local) to connect to the local instance of SQL.

On a separate note, if it is a small app, consider using SQL Compact instead.